# Get json field values from a response when using robotframework

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

[image: The response I was talking about illustrated here]                                                                   I need to capture json responses from a test setup using robotframework.
Up-till now I have not seen a way to do that in the stack.
Anyone have ideas regarding the same

Comment: can you please be more specific? what do you mean by "capture json responses?"

Comment: I have attached a figure so as to be more clear

Comment: Would this help? robotframework-httplibrary, please follow the link. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-httplibrary/0.4.2

Comment: Let me work my way through it and decide whether that is useful . I will ratify this as the answer if I find it useful. Thnx for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that library: [robotframework-requests](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests)

You can do something like:

```
Create Session  url     http://192.168.1.105
${resp}=    Get Request     url     manage?k=XXXX
// then use ${resp.json()}
```